# TS: What is the best way of getting decorator properties in children DTO of DTOs?

Tags: typescript, decorator, dto, typescript-decorator

I have two DTOs that looks like this

```
//MyDTO.controller.ts
export class MyDTO{
  @CustomDecorator
  readonly PropertyA: string

  readonly PropertyB: MyDTO2
}

//MyDTO2.controller.ts
export class MyDTO2{
  @CustomDecorator 
  readonly childProperty: string
}
```

The @CustomDecorator is supposed to add property fields to the class ( in this example it is customField), and the function looks like this

```
function CustomDecorator(target: any, key: string) {
  if (!target.customField) {
    target.customField = []
  }
  target.customField.push(key);
}
```

I can see propertyA from the below code, but what is the best solution for getting childProperty from MyDTO2 through using dtoExample['customField']?

```
    const dtoExample = new MyDTO();
    const propertiesOfDto = dtoExample['customField'];
    // propertiesOfDto = ['propertyA']
```

I have tried to use the Reflect library and changed the logic in the decorator class to get and set metadata, but this did not seem to work because the DTO threw a typeError in the getMetadata function.
MyDTO is undefined when I instantiate it so I cannot get PropertyA /PropertyB from it, much less access the properties.

Comment: As of now, decorators cannot change the type of a class. However, this may change in future as the team behind TypeScript is [discussing the viability](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) of this feature.